# angularjs converting & to &amp; in a variable coming from flask server

Tags: python, html, angularjs, flask

I am a noob in AngularJS and Flask and I'm getting this issue.

When I don't use AngularJS my `auth_url` is correct. But when I start using AngularJS, it's converting the `&` in my `auth_url` to `&amp;amp;`

here is my code.

```js
var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('customInterpolationApp', []);

customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']}]');
});

customInterpolationApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.label = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=214209400059-20bdd3dhe7hnj4b1vjf76btp7eklo7ia.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2FgCallback&scope=profile+email&state=SC1KqZJfjJ12zTrEn2Rm66GGIXGLBj&access_type=offline";
  $scope.auth_url = "'{{auth_url}}'"
});
```

When I see in the console, the value of `$scope.auth_url` has `&amp;amp;` in place of `&`. as its a link the code is breaking.

I have tried

```
$scope.auth_url = "{{auth_url}}"

$scope.auth_url = {{auth_url}}
```

but both are not working and they are still converting the `&` to `&amp;amp;`

Comment: Do you want the URL with `&amp;` or with `&` symbol?

Comment: Check https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp and see if it helps

Comment: no, my link is already uri encoded. its getting html encoded for somereason ie the conversion of & in the {{auth_url}} variable to & amp ;  which shouldnt happen